# config sticked in laravel app on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I've deploy a laravel API some months ago into a shared hosting (banahosting). It's been working fine until yesterday that all API endpoints returns an error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user '####'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select `destinations`.*, (select count(*) from `experiences` where `destinations`.`id` = `experiences`.`destination_id`) as `experiences_count` from `destinations` order by `id` desc) in file /###/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 669
```

Its weird because no-one else than me has access to the hosting, so i supposed that maybe some strange security function of this shared hosting has changed the password of the db user so i just changed it again, updated the .env file and ran the commands to clear artisan cache but the error has remained.

I've tried creating a new DB user and then i found the real problem: even when i changed the db user on the .env file, the error says that the user which is trying to access is the same. I mean, the error should say something like "Access denied for user '**NEW_USER**'@'localhost'" but instead it says "Access denied for user '**OLD_USER**'@'localhost'"

I also tried setting directly the user and password into the file /config/database.php or deleting completely the .env file but the error is exactly the same.

The support team of the hosting tried to help me too, they told me that they cleaned the cache of the server but it didn't work and they don't know what could be happening.

The command after every changed i've tried is `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`, i've also tried with `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan optimize`

Comment: Did you tried to restart nginx/apache service on host ?

Comment: If you can try php artisan tinker on server to open the REPL. And post that try echoing env  data using `echo env('YOUR_KEY') `

Comment: @Octet i can't because it's a shared hosting but i will ask to the support team for it. Thanks!

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi i've try echoing env('DB_USERNAME') on tinker and it shows the correct db username but i don't know what it could mean

Comment: @KenRamirez Yes, It would be nice to try this. You'd face the same issue if you were running your app running with php artisan serve, you wouldn't have your new env values until you'd restart php artisan serve. It could be something similar on your server.

Comment: @KenRamirez is this for single route or all route .?

Comment: @Octet they told me that it's not neccesary restart any service because it's a shared hosting but they remounted cPanel, the error remains

Comment: @KamleshPaul all routes. I also tried with php artisan route:clear